# Ubuntu loaded with wrong kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, uefi

I've updated Ubuntu KDE from 19.04 to 19.10. After that it stopped booting (at least the monitor is black and goes in a power saving mode). However, if I go to Advanced menu in grub it has two kernels and the last one the newest one is working quite well. I cannot understand why grub doesn't load this kernel. It doesn't event try to boot it.

Results of: `grep -A100 submenu  /boot/grub/grub.cfg |grep menuentry`

```
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-e6c76e6e-3a21-46e6-a06d-919030b0ecd8' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-23-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-23-generic-advanced-e6c76e6e-3a21-46e6-a06d-919030b0ecd8' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-23-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-23-generic-recovery-e6c76e6e-3a21-46e6-a06d-919030b0ecd8' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-36-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.0.0-36-generic-advanced-e6c76e6e-3a21-46e6-a06d-919030b0ecd8' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-36-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.0.0-36-generic-recovery-e6c76e6e-3a21-46e6-a06d-919030b0ecd8' {
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
```

I've tried to set GRUB_DEFAULT by guides found in the Internet but with no luck.

Here is a setting I've tried to set
`GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-e6c76e6e-3a21-46e6-a06d-919030b0ecd8>gnulinux-5.0.0-36-generic-recovery-e6c76e6e-3a21-46e6-a06d-91903-919030b0ecd8"`

Indeed I did `sudo update-grub2` before reboot but still it loads non-working kernel (at least with 19.10)

Comment: "*and the last one the newest one is working*"?    I'm not sure what you mean?  The 5.3 is the latest kernel, last one appears to be a 5.0 from 19.04 or do you mean 5.3.0-23?  Being specific can be helpful.  The 5.0 series of kernels reach EOL next month so I'd suggest using them is only a temporary fix (if security matters) if that's what you're trying to make default.

Comment: @guiverc Well. I didn't actually see `3` in Kernel versions. Actually I can only work on `5.0.0-36` by some reason. Only this kernel works

Comment: Please show `sudo grub-editenv list`

Comment: @nobody it does nothing

Comment: I know of at least one other person having issues with 5.3.0-23. I think 5.3.0-24 will be out shortly. Meanwhile that person was O.K. with 5.3.0-19.